# How to get thread object by id?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stdthread

Let's say that some thread has `std::thread::id myId` of some other thread. Now I want to retrieve the `std::thread` object associated with `myId` so I can `.join()` it. Is it possible in `std`? Or do I have to track it manually?

Comment: Why don't you store a pointer to `std::thread` instead of the id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I don't recommend this if you can avoid it. Its a bad design even on platforms where it will work. I present it as an academic exercise to satisfy curiosity.**

AFIK there is no standard way to do it. If you don't require portability and you *really* want to do this...

On some platforms (Mac and probably Linux for example) `std::thread` will just be a wrapper around the underlying `pthread_t` which you already have as it is the same as the `std::thread::id` you already have. In other words you can cast that to `pthread_t` and pass it to `pthread_join`. the`std::thread` object associated with it *should* behave as it would if you had called `join()` on it.

Example program (tested on macOS 10.13):

```
auto t1 = std::thread([]() {
    printf("Thread ran.\n");
});

auto id = t1.get_id();
pthread_t* ptr = (pthread_t*)&id;
int ret = pthread_join(*ptr, nullptr);
if (ret == 0) {
    printf("thread joined.\n");
}

ret = pthread_join(*ptr, nullptr);
if (ret != 0) {
    printf("error: %d\n", ret);
}

try {
    t1.join();
} catch (std::system_error& e) {
    printf("%s\n", e.what());
}
```

output:

> Thread ran.
>
> thread joined.
>
> error: 3
>
> thread::join failed: No such process

As you can see `pthread_join()` did not return an error the first time it was called indicating that indeed the thread was joined. The second time it returns `ESRCH` because the thread was already joined; same as the `t1.join()`.

Do note that `t1.joinable()` will still return true if the implementation is built to simply check that the `pthread_t` is non 0. The `std::thread` will be destroyed without error when it goes out of scope; I did not detect any errors when running with Asan/Ubsan/Tsan; YMMV.

Comment: How can one update the `std::thread`'s `id`-member upon having joined the native thread without it?

Comment: @Deduplicator in what way and for what purpose does it need to be updated? assuming the implementation in question the `id` is just a `pthread_t`. I already stated this wont be portable.